# Function that checks if a point is in radius

Tags: haskell

I need help with this function. It has to return 2 lists. All the points, that are in the radius in the first and all others in the second. This is what I wrote, but it gave me so much errors.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
splitPoints :: Point -> Double -> [Point] -> ([Point], [Point])
splitPoints (x, y) r (z:zs)
    |(_, _) _ []                    = ([][])
    |x * x + y * y <= r * r         = (x,y) : (splitPoints (x, y) r zs) []
    |otherwise                      = [] (x,y) : (splitPoints (x, y) r zs)
```

Comment: Is the first argument the center point?

Comment: Please post the errors.

Comment: the first argument is the center point, the second one - the radius. And the third one is the list of points that we check

Comment: You perform pattern matching in the guard.

Comment: these are the errors:
 * Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> [a0] -> Bool'
                  with actual type `(a6, b0)'
    * The function `(_, _)' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `(a6, b0)' has none
      In the expression: (_, _) _ []
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `splitPoints':

Comment: Please do not put errors in the comment section, they are hard to read. Future readers of your problem will appreciate it if they can learn from this in a clear manner. You can help them achieve this by putting your errors in the problem section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to move the pattern match for the empty list out of the guard and as a seperate function clause.

Second, I suggest putting the recursive call in a `where` clause to seperate the points in the circle and outside of the circle. Then you can check in your guard, in which list you have to insert the point.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

splitPoints :: Point -> Double -> [Point] -> ([Point], [Point])
splitPoints _ _ [] = ([], [])
splitPoints center@(centerx, centery) r ((x,y):zs)
    | (x-centerx)**2 + (y-centery)**2 <= r**2 = ((x,y) : inside, outside)
    | otherwise                               = (inside, (x,y) : outside)
  where (inside, outside) = splitPoints center r zs
```

Comment: can you tell me how does this works: (inside, outside) = splitPoints center r zs

Comment: This is a pattern match on the recursive call, `inside` is the list of points that are in the radius and `outside` the list of points that aren't in the radius, that way you can construct the resulting list

Answer (score 3):

The reason this does not work is because you make some syntactical errors:

1. pattern matching in the guards;
2. `([][])` is not a 2-tuple with two empty lists;
3. `[] (x, y)` will try to perform function application with `[]` the function.

You furthermore calculate the distance of the center point to the origin, not the distance between two points. So either all `Point`s will be in the left sublist, or in the right sublist.

We can fix this with:

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

splitPoints :: Point -> Double -> [Point] -> ([Point], [Point])
splitPoints _ _ [] = ([], [])
splitPoints (x0, y0) r ((x, y):zs)
    | dx*dx + dy*dy <= r*r = ((x, y):ra, rb)
    |otherwise = (ra, (x, y):rb)
    where dx = x - x0
          dy = y - y0
          (ra,rb) = splitPoints (x0, y0) r zs
```

But this still does not look very elegant. I think it is probably better to *separte your concerns*. You can for example use [**`partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) to divide items in two lists: one that satisfies a predicate, and one where the items do not satisfy this predicate.

So now it is a matter of designing a predicate. We can do that with:

```
import Data.List(partition)

type Point = (Double, Double)

splitPoints :: Point -> Double -> [Point] -> ([Point], [Point])
splitPoints (x0, y0) r = partition p
    where p (x, y) = dx*dx + dy*dy <= r * r
              where dx = x - x0
                    dy = y - y0
```

Comment: Could you tell me how does this works: (ra,rb) = splitPoints (x0, y0) r zs

Comment: @MitkoDimitrov: you make a recursive call on the rest of the list, and you then unpack the tuple in two variables `ra` and `rb`.